# insert list element into a 2nd list of lists at intervals of 2 in python

Tags: python

I was wondering how to insert each element in a list into a second list of lists at intervals of 2 with the 1st insertion at the beginning of the list of lists.

```
lis1 = [['g'],['h'],['i']]
lis2 = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e'],['f']]

Expected = [['g'],['a'],['b'],['h'],['c'],['d'],['i'],['e'],['f']]
```

My thought process is to set pos to 2 and check while length of lis1 is greater than 0, pop element at index 0 (first index) and insert into lis2 and move to the next 2 positions but I am not sure of how to start or if my thought process is possible.

Comment: In case of `lis2` having fewer than twice the elements of `lis1`, do you expect the remaining elements of `lis1` to be appended with empty lists separating them, or together? And what if `len(lis2) == len(lis1) // 2 - 3` - would you expect the last element of `lis2` to be the only thing separating the last two elements of `lis1`? I.e. can you give expected results for `lis1 = [['g', 'h', 'i']]; lis2 = [['a'], ['b']]` and for `lis1 = [['g', 'h']]; lis2 = [['a']]`?

Comment: okay lis2 will never have fewer elements than lis1 in my use case but that will be interesting to know. Lis 1 always contains half the elements in lis2

Comment: I've added a few examples and an alternate solution below - no issues with @rafaelc 's solution though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can use `chain.from_iterable` and `zip`

```
import itertools

>>> chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable
>>> s = iter(lis2)
>>> list(chain(zip(lis1,s,s)))
[['g'], ['a'], ['b'], ['h'], ['c'], ['d'], ['i'], ['e'], ['f']]
```

Comment: wow I did not know about itertools. Worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The previous solution is correct, but I figured there is an interesting different approach without library use:

```
import itertools


def combine1(l1, l2):
    chain = itertools.chain.from_iterable
    s = iter(lis2)
    return list(chain(zip(lis1, s, s)))


def combine2(l1, l2):
    il2 = iter(l2)
    return [x for t in [(y, next(il2, None), next(il2, None)) for y in l1] for x in t]


lis1 = [['g'],['h']]
lis2 = [['a']]

print("Accepted answer: ", combine1(lis1, lis2))
print("Alternate answer: ", combine2(lis1, lis2))

lis1 = [['g'],['h'],['i']]
lis2 = [['a'],['b']]

print("Accepted answer: ", combine1(lis1, lis2))
print("Alternate answer: ", combine2(lis1, lis2))

lis1 = [['g']]
lis2 = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d']]

print("Accepted answer: ", combine1(lis1, lis2))
print("Alternate answer: ", combine2(lis1, lis2))

lis1 = [['g'],['h'],['i']]
lis2 = [['a'],['b'],['c'],['d'],['e'],['f']]

print("Accepted answer: ", combine1(lis1, lis2))
print("Alternate answer: ", combine2(lis1, lis2))
```

Whether that's correct though really depends on what can be expected to be found in `lis1` and `lis2`.

The output of that script:

```
Accepted answer:  []
Alternate answer:  [['g'], ['a'], None, ['h'], None, None]
Accepted answer:  [['g'], ['a'], ['b']]
Alternate answer:  [['g'], ['a'], ['b'], ['h'], None, None, ['i'], None, None]
Accepted answer:  [['g'], ['a'], ['b']]
Alternate answer:  [['g'], ['a'], ['b']]
Accepted answer:  [['g'], ['a'], ['b'], ['h'], ['c'], ['d'], ['i'], ['e'], ['f']]
Alternate answer:  [['g'], ['a'], ['b'], ['h'], ['c'], ['d'], ['i'], ['e'], ['f']]
```

Note that the final case uses the example data and has the same result either way.

Since it came up, a different and more generalised approach:

```
def generate_combine3(l1, l2, n):
    il2 = iter(l2)
    for x in l1:
        yield x
        for _ in range(n):
            yield(next(il2, None))
```

Since this is a generator, to get the exact same behaviour as the previous function, you'd need to wrap with list:

```
def combine3(l1, l2, n):
    return list(generate_combine3(l1, l2, n))
```

Comment: I like your way of thinking ;} If you wanna keep my answer, change `zip` to `itertools.zip_longest` and we would get same answers !

Comment: Interesting examples and exclusion of other packages. This seem more general and applicable to many other use cases. Will this to apply to situations where you need to insert at positions other than 2nd position?

Comment: @Starter similar to the accepted solution, you'd end up with longer statements as the number of positions increases, e.g. `list(chain(zip(lis1, s, s, s)))` and `(y, next(il2, None), next(il2, None), next(il2, None))` for 3rd position. To generalise for n-th position, you'd probably implement a simple loop instead of having a single expression or `zip` call.

Comment: True. I have experienced that scenario even with the modified code for nth position.